# Не могу принять большие данные через POST

Tags: javascript, php, post

Отправляю текст на сервер, средние тексты он принимает и записывает в базу нормально (~124тыс. символов) а вот большие не хочет принимать(~200тыс. символов). Браузер отдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

Уже всё перепробовал... В чем здесь может быть проблема??

php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize=256M
max_input_vars=4000000
max_execution_time=50000
post_max_size=256M
```

js post:

```
    var result = JSON.stringify(callback);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var data = 'result=' + encodeURIComponent(result);
    request.open("POST", site, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send(data);
```

Comment: 403 => forbidden. Я очень сомневаюсь, но: в СУБД в каждого типа данных есть своё ограничение на max к-во символов. По ошибке это не оно, но мало ли

Comment: @bully А можете показать запрос? Например в `curl` тоже может стоять ограничение по времени.

Comment: ты настроил только пхп.А общается с к лиентом у тебя не пхп а веб-сервер. в котором тоже есть настройки. и у которого тоже есть лог ошибок, в котором человеческим языком написано, в чем проблема

Comment: СУБД стоит LONGTEXT.
Клиент шлёт данные через js обычным POST запросом.
`XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Я добавил ко всему js запрос, если это на что-то может повлиять.

Comment: Зависит от сервера и его кода, HTTP ошибки можно возвращать в той же Laravel как response(403, 'BlahBlah'), у вас есть доступ к серверу или его документации чтобы проверить где эта ошибка возвращается и почему?